# trying to understand boost queue examples

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, queue

I'm trying to understand the queue examples from boost.org. Specifically the simplest, the single producer single consumer queue. Consider the code below.

Why is consumer_count atomic but not producer_count? They're both changing within their own threads.

On the line declaring the queue why is there a constant in the angle brackets? I thought in construct `foo<bar>` , bar was just a modifier of foo, like `Vector<double>`. I know it's setting the size of the queue but why angle brackets and not parentheses like a normal function call?

Look at the empty while loop within the for loop in producer. If the queue fills up, the push function returns false. Wont this then go into an infinite loop?

I don't understand the lockfree concept. What is lock?

Why are there 2 while pop loops in consumer?

If producer & consumer are running concurrently with equal priority the size of the queue should hover near 0 or 1 right? Or does it  fill then dump over & over?

Done is set in main before the consumer thread is joined. I'm confused. What is the sequence of events near the end of this code?

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
int producer_count = 0;
boost::atomic_int consumer_count (0);
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<int, boost::lockfree::capacity<1024> > spsc_queue;
const int iterations = 10000000;
void producer(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != iterations; ++i) {
        int value = ++producer_count;
        while (!spsc_queue.push(value));
    }
}
boost::atomic<bool> done (false);
void consumer(void)
{
    int value;
    while (!done) {
        while (spsc_queue.pop(value)) ++consumer_count;
    }

    while (spsc_queue.pop(value)) ++consumer_count;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "boost::lockfree::queue is ";
    if (!spsc_queue.is_lock_free()) cout << "not ";
    cout << "lockfree" << endl;

    boost::thread producer_thread(producer);
    boost::thread consumer_thread(consumer);

    producer_thread.join();
    done = true;
    consumer_thread.join();

    cout << "produced " << producer_count << " objects." << endl;
    cout << "consumed " << consumer_count << " objects." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Too  many questions in the one post. You definitely need some book about C++/Boost.

Answer (score 2):

Single Producer, Single Consumer says it all: it has atomicity **as long** as all writes occur on exactly one thread, and all reads on exactly one other thread. This is **the contract**.

The contract gives way to a lot of optimization due to memory ordering¹.

> Why is consumer_count atomic but not producer_count? They're both changing within their own threads.

Not sure. Consider asking the author(s) of the sample.²

> On the line declaring the queue why is there a constant in the angle brackets? I thought in construct foo , bar was just a modifier of foo, like Vector. I know it's setting the size of the queue but why angle brackets and not parentheses like a normal function call?

The ringbuffer has static capacity. It's in angle brackets because it's a template argument, and not a function argument. Doing things statically again gives the compiler much more knowledge to optimize at compile time.

Regardless of the goals, the decision what to make static and dynamic is an API design choice.

> Look at the empty while loop within the for loop in producer. If the queue fills up, the push function returns false. Wont this then go into an infinite loop?

Yes. This is normal in lockfree processing. The alternative would be... to block until the situation is resolved, but that introduces: locks. Locks have much higher latency overhead. So the cost of busy looping can be preferred in favour of the lowest possible latency.

> I don't understand the lockfree concept. What is lock?

See my previous paragraph. It follows that lock-free makes no sense on a single-core system. It makes most sense on a system where each thread can run on a dedicated CPU core, tasks typically take very little time, low latency is more important than energy efficiency and there are no background processes interfering with optimal CPU utilization.

> Why are there 2 while pop loops in consumer?

The first runs until `done` is reset. The second drains the queue in case there are remaining elements.

> If producer & consumer are running concurrently with equal priority the size of the queue should hover near 0 or 1 right? Or does it fill then dump over & over?

That's timing dependent and as such is undefined: it depends on CPU architecture, system load, pipeline efficiency, cache invalidations, etc. Yes, considering that both consumer/producer are basically do-nothing loops you might expect the system to be able to attain some "stable" load cadence where the queue averages `n` items.

> Done is set in main before the consumer thread is joined. I'm confused. What is the sequence of events near the end of this code?

The producer runs till completion. That thread is joined in main. Done is reset. The first consumer loop exits. If there are more remaining elements queued, the second consumer loop consumes them. The consumer thread ends. That thread is joined in main.

---

¹ specifically, memory_order `acquire` in the consumer and `release` in the producer, but these are implementation details you don't need to worry about as long as you satisfy the usage requirements

Comment: Thanks Sehe. Back to the infinite while loop in producer. I wanted to see what would happen if the queue filled. So I changed it so that I push an array of 2 values into the queue instead of just one. I still pop just 1. I think it is filling up since I push in 20,000,000 values but only get back about 16,000,000 (it varies run to run.) But the code still ends. Why doesn't it get stuck in that infinite while loop when push returns false?

Comment: Because the `done` flag gets reset.The producer spins as long as necessary for the consumer to make enough room for all the elements